# Company is not a module (previous definition of Company was here)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a `Company` model. But I have also described the namespace `company` in the routes. That is, as a result, I am obliged to use the `Company` module.

And as a result I get the error:

```
TypeError - Company is not a module
previous definition of TypeError was here:
```

And points to the module name on line 3:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Company # <- this
  module Manager
    class OrdersController < Company::Manager::BaseController
      # ...
```

This is a working option:

```rb
class Company::Manager::OrdersController < Company::Manager::BaseController
```

But this is not entirely correct.

Please tell me how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You are not **obliged** to use a `Company` module because you use it in the routes somewhere. You can define which controller should respond to the route explicitely.

```
get 'profile', action: :show, controller: 'companies/manager/orders'
```

See more about the various options in the [Routing Guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).

As you figured out, you cannot have modules and classes with the same name in the same runtime. A workaround might be do pluralize the module name (`Companies`). Maybe you can provide the routes in your question, to investigate?

Comment: The code that you showed - how to use it if, for example, there are a lot of resources inside the namespace company? I'm using this namespace and Company::Manager::BaseController to get company data and use that data in all child resources (controllers).

Comment: It is important for me that all child resources come from one parent, in which there would be a management of company data.

Comment: Alternatively, which you also described, is to rename the Company controller to, for example, Companies or CompanyRoot. But in this case, the use of the plural is not very correct. And I'm curious to know if there is any other good way out of this situation?

Comment: "should avoid" is a bit misleading maybe this should read "As you figured out [you cannot have a module and class] with the same name."

Comment: @Colibri I cannot properly answer your questions without making assumptions. I guess really publishing more details about your scenario is necessary. Another way might be to have something like `Appname::Company::Manager::BaseController` .

Comment: @felix Thank you for your help. In general, I figured out how to solve this problem. I have one question left. How bad is it to use the one-line solution that I demonstrated in the text of problem?

Comment: @Colibri google, or search SO for, ruby constant lookup. This will explain the implications of using that naming convention vs nesting modules.